# HTML email : remove border between <td> buttons in Outlook 2007

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2007

I try to hide or remove a border that is displayed between 2 call-to-actions in Outlook 2007.

This border isn't displayed over the background image of my email but appears over the background color in Outlook 2007 (Outlook doesn't support the bg img) and I'v tried many things to put it off.

Here is the screen :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC5cV.gif

And this is my source code for this part :

```
<table class="table-inner" width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-link-style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;" align="center" height="36" style="border-radius: 20px; border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(1, 119, 181);">
            <a href="" style="color:#FFFFFF;" target="_blank">
            Link 1
            </a>
        </td>
        <td width="25">
        </td>
        <td align="center" height="36" bgcolor="#5eaade" style="border-radius: 20px; border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(94, 170, 222);">
            <a href="" style="color:#ffffff;" target="_blank">
            Link 2
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Please help me to remove this awful "bottom" line between the 2 buttons ?

**Regards**

Comment: That must come from CSS elsewhere?

Comment: Hi Alex, this is the css code : `table{
   border-spacing:0;
   table-layout:fixed;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  table table table{
   table-layout:auto;
  }
  table td{
   border-collapse:collapse;
  }` Do you notice something ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed !

In the css head I changed :

`table td{
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }`

for :

`table td{
            border-collapse:separate;
        }`

But 2 other buttons below did not display correctly anymore... So I forced a :

`style="border-collapse:collapse;"`

directly in their `<td>` code.

:)